# How to make Portable QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, portable

Is it possible to make QGIS 3 portable with changed location for Qgis setup parameters folder.

For QGIS 2 it looked like this in qgis.bat file:

> qgis --optionspath "X:\qgis" --configpath "X:\qgisini"

For QGIS 3 it doesn't work. Setup parameters are default placed in:

> C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\QGIS

Comment: You can do a tutoriel to convers the QGIS 3.0.2 on a portable version ? I read this explenation : https://www.sigterritoires.fr/index.php/en/
And you suggest that the difference is in the build of qgis.dat ? Best regards

Comment: A big problem seems to be paths with spaces. It is not possible to specify a relative path with spaces after "--profiles-path". Does anyone know this problem?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Could you please provide further context and a solution to your answer? You may otherwise add comments to the question.

Answer (score 10):

Those parameters have been removed in favour of the new `--profiles-path` option. You can set this to the root folder that will contain the profiles for the sessions

`--profiles-path C:\temp\myqgisprofiles\`

On Windows make a shortcut to the qgis-bin.exe and attach the parameter to the 'target' field.

This will make

`C:\temp\myqgisprofiles\profiles\default`

When run the first time.

Profiles are a new feature in QGIS 3 to keep settings and plugins, etc isolated from each other.

Comment: It's my last line in qgis.bat file below but QGIS still reads settings from `...AppData\Roaming` with warnings:
`Unable to load C:\qgis-bin.exe`
`Unable to load C:\QGIS3.0\bin\--profile-path`.  

A part of my **qgis.bat**
`start "QGIS" /B "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\qgis-bin.exe --profile-path "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\myqgisprofiles %*`

Answer (score 4):

The given option in the above answer is incorrect (*profile* instead of *profiles*) - the correct option is:

```
--profiles-path C:\temp\myqgisprofiles\
```

You can see the complete list of command line options of QGIS by running it in the command shell using the command line option *--help*:

```
qgis-bin.exe --help
```

(Running QGIS 3.0.2)

BTW: I don't have enough reputation yet, to add this as a comment to the answer above ...

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Still ini files are stored in `...AppData\Roaming\OGIS3`,not in `C:\temp\myqgisprofiles\` [link to my qgis.bat](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jwojb1urnmheq9h/qgis.bat?dl=0)

Answer (score 2):

In the same place of the file ***OSGeo4W.bat***, create a bat file with the instructions:

```
@echo off
call OSGeo4W.bat make-bat-for-py
call OSGeo4W.bat o4w_env
call OSGeo4W.bat py3_env
call OSGeo4W.bat qt5_env
call OSGeo4W.bat qgis --profiles-path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\Profiles\
```

To this point, I have not been able to execute grass scripts, but work fine SAGA and GDAL

If want use Grass script edit the file ***grass74.bat***

in the text:

```
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=@osgeo4w@
```

with the text:

```
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%
```

Comment: please place your code in code blocks for readability.

Answer (score 1):

It seems "`--profiles-path`" option is enabled in case of using with "`--profiles-name`" .

example in bat file

```
start "QGIS" /B "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\qgis-bin.exe
 --profiles-path "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\settings" --profiles-name default
```

Comment: Still the same problem, QGIS profile folder was created in `...AppData\Roaming`

Answer (score 1):

This batch seems to work, adding a /qgisconfig directory in the current one to store QGIS config :

```
set DRV_LTR=%~dp0

REM set a specific Qgis variable with a variable setting before
set OSGEO4W_ROOT=%DRV_LTR%qgis

REM add a new path to the system path
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\bin;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin

REM if the bat file find one argument (project name), open it. Else open a Qgis program with a new empty project
if "%1" == "" (start "QGIS" /B %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\qgis.bat --profiles-path %DRV_LTR%qgisconfig) else (start "QGIS" /B %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\qgis-ltr.bat --profiles-path %DRV_LTR%qgisconfig --project %1)
```