# QGIS 3 - Change location of profile folder

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

My Windows user profile at work is stored on a network drive, which causes all kinds of trouble with QGIS. So I want to place it somewhere on my C:\ drive. I found out about --configpath, but that only works for QGIS 2 (I tried it and it doesn't work in QGIS 3 anymore. QGIS would always complain, like this:

[image]

Apparently [there is now a user profile feature](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/7b92f1f1e445e069db0a6fb454318ad789c98778) in QGIS3, which enables the creation of profiles in QGIS. Sadly, it wont let me change the directory in the "create new profile" dialogue.
[image]

So how can I change the location of my profile folder now in QGIS 3?

...and if it helps, the problem I'm trying to solve by doing this, is related to the Qgis plugin "dataPlotly". And that discussion went like this: [Github](https://github.com/ghtmtt/DataPlotly/issues/85)

Comment: I actually found that post before. But didn't realize the typo, as mentioned in the comments (profile-path instead of profiles-path). It wasn't edited in the answer for some reason. I did that now. Everything is working now...

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it works with the parameter

`--profiles-path <dir>`

There was a critical typo on [How to make Portable QGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277336/how-to-make-portable-qgis-3/277358#277358) , so I edited that post.

It's working now.